# How can you display document file sizes next to a media link button?

Tags: 8, theming, media

I'm trying to display the file size of a file next to a media link button on a page.

I have two content types with a media entity reference field in each. Each field is restricted to only pull from a file media type. What I was trying to do was create a twig variable using a field preprocess and pop that variable inside each of my field templates. However, my preprocess below doesn't seem to be displaying the file size as I want. What am I doing wrong?

```
function theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {

  $pdf_fields = [
    'field_1',
    'field_2'
  ];

  if (in_array($element['#field_name'], $pdf_fields) && $element['#entity_type'] == 'node') {

    if ($variables['items'][0]) {

      $field_name = $element['#field_name'];

      $node = $element['#object'];
      // Get first referenced media id.
      $media_id = $node->$field_name->target_id;
      // Get file object.
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($media_id);
      if ($file) {
        // Get file size.
        $file_size = format_size($file->getSize());
        // Set file size variable.
        $variables['file_size'] = $file_size;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Twig field template

```
{% for item in items %}
  <a href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" class="button">Download Paper</a><span>(PDF | {{ file_size }})</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you need to get the file field id off the media object too, right now you are doing File::load on the media entity which will return null or the wrong file. Load the media entity and grab the file field just like you are doing for the Node media field. Check theme_preprocess_file_link for some more hints. If you render the media field as default and setup that media type to display as Generic File (core), won't this problem solve itself?

Comment: This should be done with a field formatter and not with templating.

Comment: Yes, hence the Generic File formatter. If you just want to get the class on the link and add the "PDF" string, you can override theme_preprocess_file_link pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try and change field formatter to generic and see if that does the trick. I know the code above works if I apply to a single field. When I tried to add a second field that's when I ran into issues.

Comment: Came across this post from leymannx about using field formatter too - https://medium.com/@leymannx/drupal-8-custom-media-field-formatter-99598b5977ae. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
function HOOK_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['file'])) {
    $variables['fileLinkDisplay'] = [
      'fileSize' => $variables['file']
        ->getSize(),
      'fileSizeFormatted' => format_size($variables['file']
        ->getSize()),
    ];
  }
}
```

`{{ fileLinkDisplay.fileSize }}`and `{{ fileLinkDisplay.fileSizeFormatted }}` will be available in your template.

**PS:** if it works then you can more filter to restrict to the content type and field you want applied for.

Additionally, there is a module that show the size https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_file_size

> Field Formatter File Size is a field formatter to display the file
>   size.

Comment: Thanks Yusef! Saw that module too, I may give that a shot too.

Comment: @PaulH have you tried the `HOOK_preprocess_file_link`, let me know about the result.